# ESL Elo formula (something wrong)

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to implement ELO formula like ESL portal have. ( http://cheater.esl.eu/uk/faq/rankmodules/ )

A first example corresponds to the example of ESL but the second and third give crazy results. Where I'm wrong?

```
    function eloEsl($k1, $k2, $g1, $g2)
{
    $per1 = $g1 / ($g1 + $g2);
    $per2 = $g2 / ($g1 + $g2);

    $E = 1/(1+ Pow(10, -($k1-$k2)/400)); 



    $Pts1 =  $k1 + 50 * ( $per1 - $E );
    $Pts2 =  $k2 + 50 * ( $per2 - $E );

    $Pts1 = round($Pts1);

    $Pts2 = round($Pts2);

    return array($Pts1, $Pts2);
}

// first test is similar to ESL example
eloEsl(1000, 1000, 3, 6); // returns  -8 / + 8

// This make crazy result !
eloEsl(1000, 1200, 5, 1); // returns  +30 / -4

// and reverse
eloEsl(1000, 1200, 1, 5); // returns  -4 / +30
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected calculated points (variable $E) is not the same for both players. So you should have $E1 and $E2.

```
$E1 = 1/(1+ Pow(10, -($k1-$k2)/400)); 

$E2 = 1/(1+ Pow(10, -($k2-$k1)/400));
```